# How to detect Timeout while receiving data through bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, settimeout, connection-timeout, read-data

In my Android application i send and receive data through Bluetooth to/from an Embedded Hardware device. I use a background **Service** to achieve this. To read bluetooth data, i use my below code,

```
public void run() {
        Log.d("DEBUG BT", "IN CONNECTED THREAD RUN");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240]; //1kb=1024bytes
        int begin = 0;
        int bytes = 0;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("-------------New Data received");
                al = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("InterruptedException during sleep");
                }

                // Read from the InputStream.

                bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);

                    for(int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
                        if(buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {

                            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                            bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                            begin = i + 1;
                            if(i == bytes - 1) {
                                bytes = 0;
                                begin = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Problem in reading Data:Input stream was disconnected "+e.getMessage());
                Handler hand = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                hand.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(BluetoothDataService.this.getApplicationContext(),"Problem in reading Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dismissDialog();
                    }
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I will send query to my Hardware unit and will be waiting for data through Bluetooth, but i didnot know how to check for timeout, I use Progress bar till i receive data but sometimes If i didnot receive data for more than 20 secs i need to alert user as "Timeout" but in my case progress is still loading ,i am stuck how to achieve this,please someone suggest how to check for timeout

Answer (score 0):

```
public void run() {
        Log.d("DEBUG BT", "IN CONNECTED THREAD RUN");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240]; //1kb=1024bytes
        int begin = 0;
        int bytes = 0;
        int timeOut = 10000;
        int currTime = 0;
        int interval = 50;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.

        while (true) {
            try {
                al = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("InterruptedException during sleep");
                }

                // Read from the InputStream.
                if(mmInStream.available() > 0){
                    // something just arrived?

                    bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);

                    currTime = 0;                               // resets the timeout

                    for(int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
                        if(buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {

                            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                            bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                            begin = i + 1;
                            if(i == bytes - 1) {
                                bytes = 0;
                                begin = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else if(currTime < timeOut) {
                    // do we have to wait some more?
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(interval);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("InterruptedException occurs while waiting for data from TPRS, "+e.getMessage());
                        printMessage("InterruptedException occurs while waiting for data from TPRS, ");
                    }
                    currTime += interval;
                }else {
                    // timeout detected
                    handleTimeOut();
                    dismissDialog();
                    currTime = 0;                           // resets the timeout
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Problem in reading Data:Input stream was disconnected "+e.getMessage());
                printMessage("Problem in reading Data");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```